# snakemake download files from sourceforce

Tags: snakemake

I try to use the  utility of snakemake for download some data (snakemake 5.2.1):

```
rule down_data2:
    input:

        HTTP.remote("https://sourceforge.net/projects/fusioncatcher/files/data/human_v90.tar.gz.ac", keep_local=True,allow_redirects=True),

    output:
        "
        "human_v90.tar.gz.ac",

    run:
        outputName = os.path.basename(input[0])
        shell("mv {input} {outputName}")
```

I have a problem on  mv comand.. Seems they save on another directory.

Answer (score 1):

URL [shouldn't include protocol](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/remote_files.html#read-only-web-http-s) `https`.

```
import os
from snakemake.remote.HTTP import RemoteProvider as HTTPRemoteProvider

HTTP = HTTPRemoteProvider()

rule down_data2:
    input:
        HTTP.remote("sourceforge.net/projects/fusioncatcher/files/data/human_v90.tar.gz.ac", keep_local=True,allow_redirects=True),
    output:
        "human_v90.tar.gz.ac"
    run:
        outputName = os.path.basename(input[0])
        shell("mv {input} {outputName}")
```